# Word that covers the following: A single episode of a series, a single movie (in a series of movies or not), an audio track (on an album or not)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

As described in the title, I'm searching for a word that covers all this different meanings. All of these meanings are in the field media but that didn't help me finding a word.

One first guess of a friend of mine: *work*. This might be accurate enough. Do you think this is the best word for it?

Comment: What makes you think there is such a word? ‘Work’ is very broad, and yes, all three things could be defined as a subtype of ‘work’ … but it’s hardly a precise definition of any of them.

Comment: I don't think there is any broad term to describe just that. However, individually, you sort of answered your own question.

Answer (score 0):

"Piece" is better than "work" IMO. "Composition" could work 
too.

But in all these cases, the usage could allow for a broader 
interpretation than you intend. So if you need a single word 
for the concept you describe, in order to refer to such things 
easily, I think you could use any of those. But you ought 
to explain your usage to the reader, rather than presume 
that it's understood.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically talking about one episode in a television series, one movie in a set of sequels, one of a group of connected books, or any of many other similar instances of a collection of creative works released over time, *installment* is an excellent word that can apply to all.

But this doesn't work for "song on an album", because the collection is released all at once, and *installment* specifically contains the idea of releases over time.